# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 16 column 1 (char 720)

Tags: python, discord.py

I started coding a chatbot for Discord and watched a YouTube tutorial based on how to make it. All the code seems to check out, but when I run it, this error displays:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 16 column 1 (char 720)
```

There were a couple of other messages in the terminal, and from what I could make out, The problem seems to originate from this line:

```
chatbot = GenericAssistant("intents.json")
```

I should also mention that I am using the neuralintents package.

This is the content in the json file:

```
{"intents" :[
  {"tag":"Greetings",
   "patterns" : ["Hello", "Hi", "What's up?"],
   "responses": ["Hello to you!", "How are you doing today?", "I am at your service."]},

  {"tag": "Questions",
  "patterns" : ["How are you?", "What are you doing?", "When were you created?"],
  "responses": ["I am doing good!", "I think you should be asking that to my owner", "I am a bot!"]},

  {"tag": "Opinions",
  "patterns": ["What do you think about", "How is the weather today", "Do you think it's gonna rain?"],
  "responses": ["I don't really know", "Seems like you're in a good mood, so I hope the weather is good today!", "Maybe"]},

  

]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Where did the `intents.json` file come from? Do you know what its contents should look like? When you try viewing the file, does it appear correct? The error message is directly telling you that the file has something wrong in it (and where in the the file the wrong thing is). We can't see this file, nor how it was created, so we can't possibly be more specific than that.

Comment: I am so sorry for posting an incomplete question. I edited it and posted the contents in the json file

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is malformed, due to an extra comma (',') character at the end of the last interesting line of the file:

```
  "responses": ["I don't really know", "Seems like you're in a good mood, so I hope the weather is good today!", "Maybe"]},
```

The comma tells the parser that another list value is coming, but then one never comes before the list is closed with the closing square brace (']') character near the end of the file.  The parser can't know that the comma is bad syntax until it reaches that final brace. It's the line containing the brace that the parser is complaining about, but the extra comma is the actual problem.

Check out this tool that I use on an almost daily basis:

> https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

If you paste your JSON into this tool and let it parse it, it will parse the JSON, but it will tell you that it had to apply a fix to be able to do so, saying: "Removed trailing comma".  You can click a checkbox to tell it not to apply any corrections to your JSON.  If you do this, you'll get a big red "INVALID" banner telling you that your JSON isn't valid, and it will explain to you exactly why that is so.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like a charm.